# Raw Base64 bytes into base64 string

Tags: objective-c, base64, nsdata

I've seen solutions for converting NSData to a string with encoding, for using `description` to get a hexadecimal representation of the string as PLIST values and for converting NSData to a double value.

How do I convert the *raw* NSData bytes into a base64 string, ignoring encoding?

EDIT: Does using `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` with 0 for options give me the raw data interpreted as string?

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? NSData has a base64EncodedStringWithOptions: method.

Comment: Yes, but if I have no options -- does that give me the raw string?

Comment: Yes, but I'm just trying to clarify if the encoding option edits the data at all by parsing it differently? If I do [description] I get hex.. wondering how they compare

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear to me. Also Base64 is not hexadecimal. Please give a concrete example of your input, the expected output and what you tried.

Comment: Edited for clarity. I'm reading NSData from vendor hardware so I don't know what the string should be. I know Base64 is not hexadecimal. I would expect description to give a raw string but it doesn't. I'm asking if using withOptions:0 gives raw bytes as NSString or if it formats it somehow inaccurately. I need the raw bytes.